# Factorial : Gamma :: Primorial :?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a unique function with the following properties:

- *f* is meromorphic on the complex plane;
- *f* is log-convex for *n* ≥ 1
- $f(n) = n\#$ for *n* prime and ≥ 2, where *#* is the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) function, and $f(1) = 1$;
- *n* and *f(n)* are both integers iff *n* is 1 or a positive prime number.

If there isn't a unique function with those properties, has anyone published any works on functions like this at least?

Comment: To have any hope of such a function existing, surely you should work with $f(n) = p_n\#$ rather than $f(n) = n\#$ (and thus change your 4th point to $n$ and $f(n)$ are both integers iff $n$ is a positive integer, not necessarily prime), right?

The function $n\#$ has long flat sections, which messes with convexity. For example, if $f(n) = n\#$ then $f(2) = 2$, $f(3) = 6$, and $f(4) = 6$. There's no way to make a convex function that interpolates those three points, let along a log-convex one.

Comment: The function I mentioned doesn't necessarily have to have $f(4) = 6$. Recall that I only said that $f(n) = n\#$ for *n* prime, so those are the only points that are fixed.

Comment: Fair enough, but convexity is still not possible. A convex function with $f(2) = 2$ and $f(3) = 6$ must have $f(4) \geq 18$ and $f(5) \geq 54$. However, $f(5) = 5\# = 30 < 54$.

Comment: Besides, what makes $x!:=\Gamma(x+1)$ *the* right extension of the factorial, and not just an arbitrary extension, is a functional equation. But the primorial has no analog functional equation, as far as I know.